# Unable to load asset(Image) Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-provider

This is my API code and I'm passing the image path from here into flutter to determine which image to load. However, all of the other data such as price or title are loading but the image is not loading and throwing an error of unable to load asset.

```js
app.post('/products',(req,res)=>{
    //console.log(req.body.LanguageID);
    //console.log(req.body.CategoryID);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).json({
        "StatusCode": 200,
        "StatusMessage": "success",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Id": "p8",
                "title": "Sufiyan",
                "ImageAsset": "assets/images/plant3.png",
                "price": 80.0                
            },
            {
                "Id": "p8",
                "title": "Sufiyan",
                "ImageAsset": "assets/images/plant1.png",
                "price": 90.0
            }
        ],
        "Message": null,
        // "localId": '8',
        // "idToken": '',
        // "error": {
        //     "message": ""
        // },
        // "expiresIn": "9"
    });
});
app.listen(5000);
```

That's how I am loading data from the provider into the widget and unable to comprehend why this is not working as I am a newbie to flutter and unable to understand it.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    //gettingData();

    final productData = Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false);
    productData.fetchData(context);
    // Create TabController for getting the index of current tab
    _controller = TabController(length: list.length, vsync: this);
    _containerheight = _totalarrayheight(8) * 140;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    final products = productData.items;
    final featuredProducts = productData.featuredItems;

    _controller!.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = _controller!.index;
        if (_controller!.index == 0) {
          _containerheight =
              140 * _totalarrayheight(products.length.toDouble());
        } else {
          _containerheight =
              140 * _totalarrayheight(featuredProducts.length.toDouble());
        }
      });
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Selected Index: " + _controller!.index.toString());
      }
    });
```

That is my provider code:

```dart
class Products with ChangeNotifier {
    late List<ProductList> _items = [];
    fetchData(context) async {
    _items = await getData();
    notifyListeners();
}
```

Widget to create the grid for product

```dart
class NewProductGrid extends StatelessWidget {
    const NewProductGrid({
    Key? key,
    required this.products,
    }) : super(key: key);

    final List<ProductList> products;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, left: 10, top: 10),
      physics:
          NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // to disable GridView's scrolling
      shrinkWrap: false,
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      itemCount: products.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ProductDetail.routeName,
              arguments: {'id': products[index].id});
        },
        child: Container(
          //padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:40.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 150,
                      width: 150,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: primary_background_six,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      child: Image.asset(
                    "${products[index].imageAsset}",
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )),
                  Container(),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                child: Text(
                  "\$${products[index].price.toInt()}",
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Morganite Light', fontSize: 50),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                child: Text(
                  "${products[index].title}",
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'PlayFairDisplay', fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
          StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 3 : 3),
      mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
     );
     }
}
```

screen code where the widget is called.

```dart
Container(
    height: _containerheight,
    child: TabBarView(
    controller: _controller,
    children: <Widget>[
    Container(
    //height: 140.0 * _totalarrayheight(tagObjs.length.toDouble()),
          child: NewProductGrid(
          products: products),
         )
```

Product list model code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductList with ChangeNotifier {
    final String id;
    final String title;
    final String imageAsset;
    final num price;
    bool isFavorite;

    ProductList({
     required this.id,
     required this.title,
     required this.price,
     required this.imageAsset,
     this.isFavorite = false,
     });
    factory ProductList.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ProductList(
        id: json['id'],
        title: json['title'],
        imageAsset: json['imageAsset'],
        price: json['price']);
     }
    factory ProductList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    print('Json:');
    print(json);
    return ProductList(
        id: json['id'] ?? '',
        title: json['title'] ?? '',
        imageAsset: json['imageAsset'] ?? '',
        price: json['price'] ?? 0);
    }

    void toggleFavoriteStatus() {
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include how you are displaying the image and did you also add assets in pubspec yaml ?

Comment: yes I did add them in pubsec.yaml

Comment: `Container( 
child: Image.asset(  
"${products[index].imageAsset}", 
fit: BoxFit.cover,`

Comment: Do you set state after the image is set?

Comment: I have created a widget that I am using on the screen like this.
   `Container(
                                            child: NewProductGrid(
                                                products: products),
                                          ),`

Comment: No, I am not setting the state after the image is set.

Comment: Try adding a set state or rebuild ui after the image is set

Comment: I have added all the code for you to have a better look at what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please add product list model too

Comment: I have added the product list model in the question

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please copy-paste the `pubspec.yaml` also into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image asset in response has an upper case i and the model of product list has image asset with lower case i

Change the model to this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 class ProductList with ChangeNotifier {
final String id;
final String title;
final String imageAsset;
final num price;
bool isFavorite;

ProductList({
 required this.id,
 required this.title,
 required this.price,
 required this.imageAsset,
 this.isFavorite = false,
 });
factory ProductList.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return ProductList(
    id: json['id'],
    title: json['title'],
    imageAsset: json['ImageAsset'],
    price: json['price']);
 }
factory ProductList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
print('Json:');
print(json);
return ProductList(
    id: json['id'] ?? '',
    title: json['title'] ?? '',
    imageAsset: json['ImageAsset'] ?? '',
    price: json['price'] ?? 0);
}

void toggleFavoriteStatus() {
isFavorite = !isFavorite;
notifyListeners();
}
}
```